# Graphql Fragment not resolving fields

Tags: graphql, adobe, aem

i am using Adobe AEM with GraphQL and i am trying to use Fragments here (because i want to query the data with Gatsby.js, but this is not related i think).

When i try to run this Query:

```
{
  testList {
    items {
      typename
      headline
    }
  }
}
```

the result is

```
{
  "data": {
    "testList": {
      "items": [
        {
          "typename": "TestModel",
          "headline": "test headline"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

which looks fine.. BUT when i try to query with fragments, the field is getting no data (headline is null)

```
{
  testList {
    items {
      typename
      ...TestModelFragment
    }
  }
}

fragment TestModelFragment on TestModel {
  headline
}

{
  "data": {
    "testList": {
      "items": [
        {
          "typename": "TestModel",
          "headline": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

can someone explain this or am i missing something here?

Comment: Did you find the root cause?

Comment: no not at all, actually i am not using AEM anymore